# Exchange operator and magnetism

Tags: electromagnetism, atomic-physics

in my atomic physics lecture notes it is said that depending on the values of the exchange operator $K_{ij}$ there can be different kinds of magnetism, say, ferromagnetism and antiferromagnetism, how can I see that?

Comment: The total wave function of the electrons is antisymmetric, and is the product of a spatial part and a spin part. If  some exchange operator favours a symmetric spatial part, you get an antisymmetric spin part (antiferromagnetism). If the exchange operator favours an antisymmetric spatial part, you get a symmetric spin part (ferromagnetism)

Comment: Hi Trimok thanks. Can be seen if the exchange operators favours the symmetric or antisymmetric part of the spatial part?

Comment: The idea is to minimize an energy. Depending on the kind of energy you minimize, you will get an symmetric or antisymmetric spatial part. I am looking to find a readable reference.

Comment: See this [reference](http://www.st-andrews.ac.uk/~jmjk/keeling/teaching/magnetism-notes.pdf)  - Chapter 1.2 - Quantum Exchange

Comment: Thank you, I see that there is no a general easy answer to my question. Looks very interesting your reference!